# Update variable without scope.$apply() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, data-binding, angularjs-scope

In my project, a canvas element shows a joystick. Through mouse/touch events, the canvas is updated to look like the user is moving the joystick. This works fine. The coordinates are held in an object like so:

```
scope.point = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    };
```

And I've added this HTML to show it to the user:

```
<span>X:{{point.x.toFixed(2)}} Y:{{point.y.toFixed(2)}}</span>
```

The problem is, when the values of scope.point.x and scope.point.y are changed (in the mouse/touch event handlers), they don't get updated in the  HTML. The only solution seems to be to add:

```
scope.$apply()
//or
scope.$digest()
```

to the render loop. This does work, but seems inelegant (imho) and makes performance dip noticeably, as expected.

Is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Though I don't think it's relevant, for reference this is the event handler code, and the render loop:

```
    //handles mouse or touch movement on joystick
    scope.mouseMove = function(evt) {
        if (leftClick == 1) { //check if left mouse button down or touch
            // get cursor or touch coordinates, saved in point object.
            if (evt.type == 'touchstart' || evt.type == 'touchmove') {
                scope.point.x = evt.targetTouches[0].pageX - joystick.offsetLeft;
                scope.point.y = evt.targetTouches[0].pageY - joystick.offsetTop;
            } else {
                scope.point.x = evt.pageX - joystick.offsetLeft - 3;
                scope.point.y = evt.pageY - joystick.offsetTop - 3;
            };
            //make coordinates relative to canvas center
            scope.point = GeometrySrv.centerCoord(scope.point, joystick);
            //if Directional Lock is ON, enforce
            if (scope.lockMode != "fullAnalog") {
                scope.point = GeometrySrv.forceDirectionLock(scope.point.x, scope.point.y, scope.lockMode);
            };
            // force coordinates into maxRadius
            if (!GeometrySrv.isInsideCircle(scope.point.x, scope.point.y, maxRadius)) {
                scope.point = GeometrySrv.forceIntoCircle(scope.point.x, scope.point.y, maxRadius);
            };
            //send coordinates back to server (websocket)
            updateJoystick(scope.point, scope.lockMode);
        };
    };

    function renderLoop() {
        //erases previous joystick position
        resetJoystick();
        // erases previous vector
        resetVector();
        //change coordinates to canvas reference
        scope.point = GeometrySrv.canvasCoord(scope.point, joystick);
        DrawSrv.drawLineFromCenter(joystickctx, scope.point.x, scope.point.y);
        if (scope.showVector) {
            DrawSrv.drawLineFromCenter(vectorctx, scope.point.x * vector.width / joystick.width, scope.point.y * vector.width / joystick.width);
        };
        //redraw joystick position
        DrawSrv.drawCircle(joystickctx, scope.point.x, scope.point.y, radius, maxRadiusBGColor);
        //change back to relative coordinates
        scope.point = GeometrySrv.centerCoord(scope.point, joystick);
        //scope.$digest();
        //call renderLoop every 15ms (60fps)
        renderReq = requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
    };
```

Comment: if events occur outside of angular core that change scope, you have to use `$apply` http://stackoverflow.com/a/31756769/1175966

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is this a definitive "not possible"? It's such a shame, because the joystick really suffers in performance, specifically on mobile when adding the $apply. If this is the case I guess I'll remove the text, as it does more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a filter, that way you still bind to the object, but your filter displays the object in a particular manner.

```
[your angular module].filter('toFixed', [function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (typeof input.toFixed == 'function')
            return input.toFixed(2);
        return input;
    };
}]);
```

And then bind it in HTML:

```
<span>X:{{point.x | toFixed}} Y:{{point.y | toFixed}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I've just tried this solution and did not solve my problem. Maybe I didn't explain myself: I would like the text to update the values of X and Y as the joystick moves, dynamically. The filter doesn't seem to trigger an update of these values. The actual variable does change (the coordinates are sent to the server through websockets, and i can see them change dynamically), it's just not shown in the <span> unless a scope.$apply or $digest is called. Thanks again for the answer, in any case.

Comment: @charlietfl Why is this discouraged? Asking from total ignorance obviously, but I read somewhere (https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135) that $digest is better for performance, as it doesn't "go up" to the rootScope, instead only acting on the current scope and children. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @xpeiro I withdraw my comment then...was something i learned several years ago and I think it was frowned upon then. The author of that post is an angular style guide guru. Could be that performance improvements have changed what I learned before

Answer (score 0):

`$apply` calls `$rootScope.$digest` internally, so use `$diggest` on local scope for better performance. For best performance abandon data binding and manipulate DOM directly. You can do this from own angular [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering! I did read about $digest vs. $apply (linked to the article in the comments of Joe Pontani's answer), but I don't see how manipulating the DOM directly will help? I did try modifying the `innerHTML` of the `<span>` in the render loop like this: `element[0].children[3].innerHTML= scope.point.x`. It worked, but performance-wise I didn't detect much improvement. Will moving this to the directive change anything? or am I missing something? I clicked on the "useful" arrow, but it seems that I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Try to [throttle](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+throttle) HTML updating.

Comment: yes, I ended up doing something similar: instead of creating a throttling function (didn't know about that, thanks for the pointer), I just added a counter to the render loop, so it calls `scope.$digest()` every 14 loops (each loop ~1000/60=17ms*14~240ms) instead of every single one. This was definitely an improvement, with an acceptable compromise. The thing is, I need the actual coordinates to be as accurate as possible (they're used in the back-end to control a robot in real-time), but the presentation on the page can be less accurate, as it's only for user feedback. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Read about [$applyAsync()](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) - it allows you to queue $digest() cycles and throttle them about every 10ms.

It is also is smart enough to know if Angular is already in a $digest() loop avoiding that annoying error that you'll get calling $apply() twice before $digest() has completed.